# How to process CSV using Julia?

Tags: julia

Could you please help me in figuring out why the code below doesn't work?

[image]

Comment: Hey! Can you explain what the code is doing and why it does not work? Otherwise, it’s very hard for a stranger to answer this question. Are you getting an error? Unexpected result? Etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of issues with your code, which seems like in many places isn't Julia code at all, but cobbled together from a variety of different languages. I'll point out a few issues below, but I would strongly recommend you start by taking a day or two to read the excellent [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/) to familiarise yourself with the basics of the language if you intend to program in it.

Some specific points:

- Reading a CSV file with the CSV package is done by calling [`CSV.File()`](https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/stable/#CSV.File)
- `showln` is not a valid Julia function, you might be looking for either `println` or `@show`
- Looping over a range of integers is generally done by looping over a `UnitRange` object, which can simply be constructed with a colon like `for i in 1:10`
- String concatenation in Julia is done using the `*` operator rather than `&`
- Comparisons are done using the `==` infix operator, using a single `=` performs an assignment of the right hand side to the left hand side
- Functions in Julia are generally not bound to objects, which seems to be what your dot notation `resultat.append!` implies. Pushing an element to an existing array is done using the `push!` function
- `[.col]` is not valid Julia syntax

It looks like you're trying to do something like:

```
using CSV, DataFrames

all_results = Float64[]

for i in 1:8
    dt = DataFrame(CSV.File(dataset[i]*"_"*kind[i]*"etcetc.csv"))
    for c in eachcol(dt)
        push!(all_results, mean(c))
        push!(all_results, median(c))
    end
end
```

Comment: I want a code little bit different. 
I have 6 documents wih lot of datas (in ".csv").
I have another csv document that lists all other documents
In the last document I want create a columns with one statistics by data. 
The users can change the statistics because have an column "operation".
In the operation column report the name of operation like "mean" or "median".
I search have the compilation time by document.

I don't know if you can understand. Sorry I'm not fluent in english. 
If you need more information for help me I can told you.

Comment: The way to do this is roughly what I described above, except that you need to put back some logic to choose the operation you want to perform (either by using simple `if elseif` clauses or by parsing the string and evaluating it as a function directly). I think to get effective help you should attempt to do things step-by-step and ask a number of different, well specified questions related to reproducible issues with specific parts of your code.